# how to disable "bytes_recv = ##; bytes_send = ##" message spam in Visual Studio Output window from C# and NetworkComms.Net app over USB to iPad

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, network-programming, usb, networkcomms.net

Only spams in **USB**, not **WIFI**.

How can we stop the continuous display (SPAM) of these messages in out **Visual Studio Output window**? We have a `C#` app built with `Visual Studio 2010` that communicates with an iPad app built with `Xamarin` Studio `Monotouch C#`.
 Both use `NetworkComms.Net` to communicate.
 When connected by USB, these debug messages spam the Output window.
 When connected by WIFI, comm is OK; there are none of these messages.

Sample of the SPAM messages:

```
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
bytes_recv = 72; bytes_send = 72
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
bytes_recv = 256; bytes_send = 256
```

Cannot find messages in our code.  Cannot find anything on Google.  Have posted request on NetworkComms.Net web.

Comment: My workaround solution is to copy Output to text file, then delete spam lines by using Visual Studio ctrl-H to replace "\nbytes_recv = *; bytes_send = *" with "" after selecting "Use Wildcards".  This deletes each spam line.  Ha, cha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find where this spam comes from.  MarcF the middleware author states that it is not from the NetworkComms.net middleware.

My workaround solution is to copy Output to text file, then delete spam lines by using Visual Studio ctrl-H to replace "\nbytes_recv = *; bytes_send = *" with "" after selecting "Use Wildcards". This deletes each spam line, and takes but 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through the source for NetworkComms.Net and the output you are reporting is not generated from within NetworkComms.Net. I would recommend investigating the other tools you are using such as the USB->TCP connection.